# Disable shipping calculation at the time of ajax produc adding to cart. Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am creating a custom plugin to get shipping rates from a third-party service. I faced with the fact that shipping rates are recalculated at the moment of adding any item to cart, and considering that shipping server responds very long, adding to cart can take 10-20 seconds.

1. Is it possible to calculate shipping costs only on the Checkout page?
2. Is it possible to recalculate shipping costs each time the Checkout page is loaded?

Answer (score 1):

Similar trouble for me, just tons of wasted API calls to fedex. I see no reason to spend the time and network traffic on that info until i'm ready to display it, and that's only on my cart and checkout pages.

So for your first question...

I found the method that looks up the actual rates, and traced it back. There is mercifully an existing filter that affords the opportunity to abort these lookups midway up the stack.

Look for the apply_filter call at the end of the show_shipping() method of the class-wc-cart.php file. This result of this method determines whether to continue performing the 'calculate_shipping' logic. Adding a one-line filter on this hook will prevent the lookups anywhere but on the cart page and the checkout page.

```
function prevent_shipping_calculation_prior_to_cart( $default ) { return is_cart() || is_checkout() ? true : false; }
add_filter('woocommerce_cart_ready_to_calc_shipping','prevent_shipping_calculation_prior_to_cart',10,1);
```

As for your second question...this is happening automatically in my case already.